# mysql: while loop shuold stop at 350, but it stops at 109

Tags: mysql, while-loop, random-data

in my MySQL workbench I have to create a wine cellar DB, i created the tables and now i have to insert values in them, i'm trying to fill a table with 350 random values, but it stops at 109 values.

What I want to do is to set vino.codice with random values from Bottiglia which has as PK codice.
In Bottiglia I have different types of bottle: wine, sparkling wine and spirits.
In vino.codice I only want the codes that matches to bottiglia.type = 'vino'.

this is one of the things that I tried:

```
drop procedure if exists in_vino;
delimiter $$
create procedure in_vino()
begin
declare c int;
declare var int;
set c = 1;
set var = (select count(codice)
            from bottiglia
            where bottiglia.tipo_bottiglia = 'vino');
start transaction;
while c <= var do
    update vino
        set codice = (select codice
                      from bottiglia
                      where bottiglia.tipo_bottiglia = 'vino'
                      order by rand()
                      limit 1);
    while c <= 175 do
            insert into vino(codice, tipo_vino, vitigno)
            select 
                codice,
                'rosso' as tipo_vino,
                elt(floor(1 + rand() * 10), 'barbera', 'dolcetto', 'nebbiolo', 'corvina', 'rondinella', 'sangiovese', 'nero d avola', 
                                 'syrah', 'cerasuolo di vittoria', 'nerello mascalese') as vitigno;
    end while;
    while c >175 and c <= 350 do
        insert into vino(codice, tipo_vino, vitigno)
        select 
            codice,
            'bianco' as tipo_vino,
            elt(floor(1 + rand() * 9), 'timorasso', 'pinot bianco', 'pinot grigio', 'soavignon blanc', 'friuliano', 'vermentino', 'pecorino', 
                         'malvasia del lazio', 'grillo') as vitigno;
    end while;
    set c = c + 1;
end while;
end $$
delimiter ;
select * from vino;
```

i checked the var variable and its value is 350.
This is  my output: 109 row(s) returned

In here you have the fiddle with table definitions and procedures to insert values that i tried: https://dbfiddle.uk/YAxr_4PR

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then see [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055).

Comment: what ends your inner while loops?  you don't change c in them

Comment: @ysth i increase the c variable at the end of the first while loop, i also tried to insert the increment in the other loops, but nothing changes.

Comment: There is a `start transaction`, but I do not see a matching `commit`? Might simply not need the `start transaction` at all?

Comment: explain in english what you are trying to do; the code as is doesn't make any sense

Comment: The published code should go into an infinite loop because the inner loops are not exited and eventually time out. Possibly replace the inner whiles with if..then insert..end if

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell you why your code only inserts 109 rows unless you provide sample data from bottiglia preferably in a fiddle together with table definitions.

Your code looks incorrect in a number of places and should time out because the inner loops never terminate and should fail with an unknown column name codice in the insert..select statements. Additionally I don't get why you attempt to update vino when it looks like setting a variable would be appropriate. You should also commit the transaction before quitting the procedure.

Below may be(or close) to what you need

```
create table vino(id int auto_increment primary key,codice int, tipo_vino varchar(10), vitigno varchar(30));
create table bottiglia(codice int);



drop procedure if exists p;
delimiter $$
create procedure p()
begin
declare c int;
declare var int;
declare vcodice int;
set c = 1;
            
while c<=350 do
    insert into bottiglia values (c);
    set c=c+1;
end while;
set var := (select count(codice)
            from bottiglia
            #where bottiglia.tipo_bottiglia = 'vino'
            );
set c = 1;
start transaction;
select c,var;
while c <= var do
    #update vino
   set vcodice = (select codice
                      from bottiglia
                      #where bottiglia.tipo_bottiglia = 'vino'
                      order by rand()
                      limit 1);
    if c <= 175 then
            insert into vino(codice, tipo_vino, vitigno)
            select 
                vcodice,
                'rosso' as tipo_vino,
                elt(floor(1 + rand() * 10), 'barbera', 'dolcetto', 'nebbiolo', 'corvina', 'rondinella', 'sangiovese', 'nero d avola', 
                                 'syrah', 'cerasuolo di vittoria', 'nerello mascalese') as vitigno;
    end if;
    if c >175 and c <= 350 then
        insert into vino(codice, tipo_vino, vitigno)
        select 
            vcodice,
            'bianco' as tipo_vino,
            elt(floor(1 + rand() * 9), 'timorasso', 'pinot bianco', 'pinot grigio', 'soavignon blanc', 'friuliano', 'vermentino', 'pecorino', 
                         'malvasia del lazio', 'grillo') as vitigno;
    end if;
    set c = c + 1;
end while;
select c;
commit;
end $$
delimiter ;
truncate table bottiglia;
call p();
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/IQa5WGGj

NB:-the fiddle does not require delimiters to be set..

Comment: thanks for your help, this is my table definition with the procedures to insert random values in the tables https://dbfiddle.uk/YAxr_4PR . i update vino because vino.codice needs to be a random values from bottiglia.codice i don't know if is the best way, but i tried different codes.